# Bootstrap and AngularJS - Putting ui-view inside a div column

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

This is a simple question, but for some reason, I'm not getting the desired result.
Here's a snippet of the code inside my index.html file

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-1">
            <div ui-view="sidebar"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-11">
            <div ui-view="content"></div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

What I'm hoping will happen is that the sidebar will take up 1 column and the rest of it will take up the remaining columns. However, when I view the page, the sidebar and the content are shown stacked on top of each other. Am I not allowed to put a ui-view inside a div container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to write 2 columns in same row:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-1">
            <div ui-view="sidebar"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-11">
            <div ui-view="content"></div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Thank You. I am an idiot for not realizing that sooner. Sorry for wasting your time